# Apache POI Java XSSFCell DataFormat not beeing applied

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, dataformat

currently im struggling setting a DataFormat to a specific row.

This is how my Excel Sheet looks like. Im having those 4 Columns.
Column 1 should take DataFormat Number
Column 2 & 3 should take DataFormat Date
Column 4 is ok
[image: This is how my Excel Sheet looks like. Im having those 4 Columns. Column 1 should take DataFormat Number Column 2 & 3 should take DataFormat Date Column 4 is ok]

```
public static void createTableRow(Sheet sheet, List<String> EDIROWKeys, int col, CellStyle style , int lastRowNum){
    
    if(sheet == null){
        return;
    }
    int lastRow = lastRowNum;
    int newRow = lastRow + 1;
    Workbook wb = sheet.getWorkbook();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat date = wb.createDataFormat();
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) sheet.createRow(newRow);
    if(row == null){
        return;
    }
    int startCol = col;
    for(String string : EDIROWKeys){
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(startCol);
    
        FOe.getFOPSessionContext().getDbContext().out().println(string);
    
        if(style != null){
        
            cell.setCellStyle(style);
        }else  {
            XSSFWorkbook wbx = (XSSFWorkbook) sheet.getWorkbook();
            XSSFDataFormat dataformat = wbx.createDataFormat();

            XSSFCellStyle cs = wbx.createCellStyle();
            if(startCol == 1){
                cs.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("#"));
            }
            cell.setCellStyle(cs);
            
        }
        cell.setCellValue(string);
        
        startCol++;
    }
    return;
}
```

This is the Method i am using to Create my rows & Columns
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
This is the resource i was getting my DataFormats from.
I also tried applying those DataFormats with HssfDataformat to my cell - no success either.

I apperciate any helpful input :)

Solved by using setCellValue(Double);...

```
if(string.matches("\\d+")){
        cell.setCellValue(Double.valueOf(string));
        startCol++;
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: After `Cell.setCellValue(java.lang.String value)` the cell contains a text value. Text values will not use number formats. You need set the cell values using `Cell.setCellValue(double value)` or `Cell.setCellValue(java.util.Date value)` or another set-cell-value-method which sets numeric values.

Comment: Thanks mate, this solved the problem. Added now some condition for numbers and date values :)!

Answer (score 1):

I see one possible case. If method argument `style` is null, new style, `XSSFCellStyle cs` is not applied to cell. Is `cell.setCellStyle(cs)` missing?

Comment: Thanks for your Input man :)! You were this time i didnt call setCellStyle(cs), i`ve edited the code , but it didnt fix the problem. Same issue still exists